# $result is empty even though the query worked?

Tags: php, sql

When i run this sql i get an error message as if $result is empty, but the query has run and my database i updated? How come $result can be empty then?

```
$query = $mysqli->query("INSERT into `message` (customer_id, msg_headline) values ($customerId, '" . $_POST["messageHeader"] . "')");
    if(isset($_POST["orderId"])) {
        $query .= $mysqli->query("UPDATE `message` SET order_id=IF('".$_POST["orderId"]."' = '', order_id, ".$_POST["orderId"].")");
    }
    $query .= $mysqli->query("INSERT into message_content (message_id, msg) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '" . $_POST["messageContent"] . "')");
    $result = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli, $query);
    if ($result) {
        do 
            if (($result = mysqli_store_result($mysqli)) === false && mysqli_error($mysqli) != '') {
                $resultMessage = "Query fail: " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
            }
        } while (mysqli_more_results($mysqli) && mysqli_next_result($mysqli)); // while there are more results
        $messageValid = 1;
        $resultMessage = "Success";
    } else {
        $resultMessage = "Database was not updated: " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
    }
```

the function will return the last $resultMessage even though the query worked!?

Comment: What do you expect an insert statement result to be? Chances are you should look for mysqli_insert_id() to get the inserted row id, and then basically say if it is not 0 or false, the query was successfull...

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: i know, but this is for logged in b2b customers, but security should be improved..

Comment: @JustinE like if(mysqli_insert_id() != 0) ?

Answer (score 0):

`$result` isn't actually empty at all.  It just doesn't have anything to display as it is an 'object'.  If you did something like `echo $result` the output would look like `Resource id #4`

You indicate `$resultmessage` is being displayed, I suspect that if, as you say, the database is being updated then you will be seeing "success".

What are you expecting to see?

Comment: but how come it doesnt go inside the if statement if $result is not empty? i mean it runs the $resultMessage in the else statement?

Comment: Are you saying it runs the "database fail" code?  If so, what is the error generated by mysqli_error($mysqli)

Comment: yes it does - message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '11' at line 1

Comment: So there's your problem.  You need to display the statement and work out what the error is.

Comment: it should already be displayed.  $resultMessage = "Database was not updated: " . mysqli_error($mysqli);

If this is a school project you should be doing the research not asking for answers.  

If this is a production project, you are in over your head.